# Blob is not a UTF-8 string field calculation

Tags: apex, json

I'm trying to compare a checksum to the checksum of the file but I'm getting the UTF- 8 string error.

```
 for(file thefile : list)
 {  
 thefile.checksum = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5',Blob.valueOf(thefile.encodedfile)).tostring();
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated on how to convert MD5 to string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want to do is get the hex values of the binary digest:

```
EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Blob MD5digest);
```

Documentation on this method can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_convertToHex).

Assuming that the `checksum` value was generated the same way, you should be able to use the string returned from `convertToHex()` for comparison:

```
thefile.checksum = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5',Blob.valueOf(thefile.encodedfile)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
for(file thefile : list)
{
    thefile.checksum= EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5',Blob.valueOf(thefile.encodedfile));
}
```